# how can I raise the volume input on audacity? I have tried using the tool bar.

Tags: audacity

How can I raise the volume input on audacity?  I have tried the tool bar.

Answer (score 1):

The "amplify" plug-in is installed with the base package. If your not getting enough volume on your inputs I would check your PC's own audio level settings. 
The audio input is set for High Definition Audio (same as SACD) which means that full volume at the inputs is about 10 volts p-p with 120db dynamic range, or a ratio of about 1 million to 1.
 Usually this means some microphones and low output devices may need an external audio booster that can boost the signal 5 to 100 times (+20db). If that seems to be the case you could search online and get one at a low cost or try other microphones and signal sources first.